# Let $T, N :V \to V$, N is nilpotent, T is invertible and $N*T = T*N$. Prove $N+T$ invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets say we have $T,N:V \to V$ . N is nilpotent, T is invertible and $T*N=N*T$.

Prove that $N+T$ is invertible.

Any suggestion on how I can prove this? we know that $\exists k$ $s.t$ $N^k=0$.

I was thinking of $(N+T)^k$ as a start but got stuck. Any Ideas?

Comment: false if $T$ is arbitrary. For example, when $T=0.$  The usual quaestion of this type is when $T=I,$ which teaches some things.

Comment: sorry, T is invertible. I will edit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$m \in \Bbb N \tag 1$

be the smallest positive integer such that

$N^m = 0; \tag 2$

if we assume $N \ne 0$ (in the contrary case there is nothing to prove), then

$m > 1; \tag 3$

we write

$T + N = T(I + T^{-1}N); \tag 4$

now,

$TN = NT \tag 5$

implies

$T^{-1}N = NT^{-1}, \tag 6$

whence

$(-T^{-1}N)^m = (-1)^m T^{-m} N^m = 0.  \tag 7$

We recall the polynomial identity

$x^m - 1 = (x - 1) \displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} x^{m - 1 - i}, \tag 8$

which we may also write as

$1 - x^m = (1 - x)  \displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} x^{m - 1 - i}; \tag 9$

we apply this identity taking

$x = -T^{-1}N, \tag{10}$

and find

$I = I - (-T^{-1}N)^m = (I + T^{-1}N) \displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} (-T^{-1}N)^{m - 1- i}, \tag{11}$

which shows that $I + T^{-1}N$ has an inverse

$(I + T^{-1}N)^{-1} =  \displaystyle \sum_0^{m - 1} (-T^{-1}N)^{m - 1- i}. \tag{12}$

Now since both $T$ and $(I + T^{-1}N)$ are invertible, so is their product

$T + N = T(I + T^{-1}N), \tag{13}$

and we are done!

Comment: Very detailed proof, thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure sir!  Cheers!

Comment: And thank you for the "acceptance"!

Answer (score 3):

Note that $N, T$ commute, so we may see the following is true for polynomials in $t, n$.

$$t+n \mid t^{k} - n^{k}$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. But there exists a $k$ such that $N^k = 0$. Pick this $k$. Then the inverse is 
$$(T^{k-1} + T^{k-2}(-N) + \ldots + T(-N)^{k-2} + (-N)^{k-1}) T^{-k}$$

Comment: The signs in the polynomial after the "..." should depend on the parity of $k$: $(T^{k-1} - T^{k-2}N + \ldots + (-1)^{k-2}TN^{k-2} + (-1)^{k-1}TN^{k-1})$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain why $t+n∣t^k−n^k$.

Comment: @romanasa Multiply out $t^{k-1} + t^{k-2}(-n) + \ldots + t(-n)^{k-2} + (-n)^{k-1}$ with $t+n$.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can not prove this. Take  $T=0$.

Comment: I modified the post with T invertible.